# T-SQL about self updating of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this `table1`:

| date | typeName | Typecode | Values1 | Values2 | Values3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | A | 01 | null | 5 | null |
| 2022-09-02 | A | 01 | null | 10 | null |
| 2022-09-01 | B | 02 | null | 30 | null |
| 2022-09-02 | B | 02 | null | 10 | null |

And the `table2`:

| date | typeName | Typecode | Values1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | A | 01 | 40 |
| 2022-09-01 | B | 02 | 50 |

I want to update table1 using the data from table2 such that

values3 = values1 - values2 and next day , values3 of previous date = values 1 or next day and so on.

| date | typeName | Typecode | Values1 | Values2 | Values3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | A | 01 | 40 | 5 | 35 |
| 2022-09-02 | A | 01 | 35 | 10 | 25 |
| 2022-09-01 | B | 02 | 50 | 30 | 20 |
| 2022-09-02 | B | 02 | 20 | 10 | 10 |

How to write the T-SQL to do that?

Comment: Not clear. Explain "values3 = values1 - values2 and next day , values3 of previous date = values 1 or next day" because as such, it doesn't mean much. Do you want to use table2 to "initialize" table1 and then we forget about it, or is table2 also populated by another process, or what ?

Comment: Table1.values3 = table2.values1 - running total(table1.values2) —> table1.values1 = table1.value3+table1.value2 : `update dtX
set values1 = rt+values2,
  values3 = rt
from
(
select t1.*, t2.values1 - sum(t1.values2) over(partition by t1.Typecode order by t1.date rows unbounded preceding) as rt
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2 on t1.Typecode = t2.Typecode
) as dtX`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty., but wirks fine
The CTE is , that we can get all needed Number s from table1 and table to get rolling

The Main SELECT use the LAG window function to get the last VaLues3, which is after the CTe not NULL anymore.

The COASLESCE is neede as for the first row of every PARTITION the LAG function will return NULL

```
WITH CTE AS
  (SELECT t1.[date], t1.[typeName],t1.[Typecode],t2.[Values1],t1.[Values2],t2.[Values1] -t1.[Values2] [Values3]
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.[date] = t2.[date] AND  t1.[typeName] = t2.[typeName]
   AND t1.[Typecode]= t2.[Typecode])
SELECT
t1.[date], t1.[typeName],t1.[Typecode]
  ,  COALESCE(LAG(t2.[Values3]) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.[typeName], t2.[Typecode] ORDEr BY t1.[date]),t2.[Values1]) [value1]
  , t1.[Values2]
  , COALESCE(LAG(t2.[Values3]) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.[typeName], t2.[Typecode] ORDEr BY t1.[date]),t2.[Values1])  
   - t1.[Values2] as [Values3]
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN CTE t2 ON t1.[date] = t2.[date] AND  t1.[typeName] = t2.[typeName]
   AND t1.[Typecode]= t2.[Typecode]
```

| date | typeName | Typecode | value1 | Values2 | Values3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | A | 1 | 40 | 5 | 35 |
| 2022-09-02 | A | 1 | 35 | 10 | 25 |
| 2022-09-01 | B | 2 | 50 | 30 | 20 |
| 2022-09-02 | B | 2 | 20 | 10 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O1P2IqB4)